# shortcut command for printf with a specific format string

Tags: bash, text-formatting, printf

I want to use a shortcut command for `printf` with a specific format string, and came up with the following.

```
local PF="printf %s\n"
$PF "Some Text"
```

It does the job, but wonder if there exist any caveats when using such an approach, that could lead to misinterpretation of the format string.

Comment: The format string could be a problem if it's more complex than just `%s\n`.    Also, you're likely to run into all sorts of quoting-related annoyances by trying to do this with a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Why execute the value of a variable when you could just use a function - that's what they're for.

   ```
   PF() { printf "%s\n" "$@" ; }
   PF "Some Text"
   ```

   or an alias:

   ```
   alias PF='printf "%s\n"'
   PF "Some Text"
   ```
2. If you really want to have a variable involved, use it to hold the format string. e.g.

   ```
   fmt="%s\n"
   printf "$fmt" "Some Text"
   ```

   If you want to keep the line lengths under, say, 80 chars, then assign the variable in two or more statements.  e.g.

   ```
   fmt="......part1......"
   fmt+="......part2......"
   fmt+="......part3......"
   ...
   ```

   This is also useful if you just want to make assigning the format string more readable, or to add individual comments about some or all of the parts.

Comment: The reason I want such a thing is because I need a compact way of printing a usage string and still be within 80 characters (including the `printf` and `fmt`).

Comment: if your format string is > 80 chars and you want to keep your line length under 80 chars then just assign it to a variable in two or more statements.  e.g. `fmt="...73 chars..."` then `fmt+="...another 72 chars"` (repeat as needed).   number of chars will vary according to indentation and other factors that might affect the positioning of the `fmt="` and `fmt+="` portions of the line (and the ending quote, of course).

Comment: Fantastic strategy.

Comment: You got that right.  My intention for such approach is to make things easily readable, and add individual comments in some instances.  Some final touches before I release the code.

Comment: Combine the function definition and the multi-statement fmt string assignment.  Depending on your exact needs, it might be useful to define the format variable as a global variable, but in most cases it's probably better to define it as a local variable in the function.

Answer (score 2):

That `$PF` in list context is invoking split+glob. The contents of `$PF` is split according to complex rules involving the `$IFS` special parameters (which have nothing to do with what happens when `bash` interprets the `printf %s\n` code for instance), and then the resulting words are subject to filename generation (aka pathname expansion aka globbing).

So, here, there are at least 2 problems:

1. the behaviour of that `$PF` is dependant on the current value of `$IFS`. By default, in `bash`, `$IFS` contains space, tab and newline, and here you do want `$PF` to be split on space, and the string otherwise doesn't contain tab nor newline. But in a context where `$IFS` has been changed to `%` for instance, you'd end up running the `"printf "` command with `"s\n"` as argument.
2. In some versions of bash (namely 5.0, I believe it was reverted in 5.1), `\` is a globbing operator (at least like here where it comes from some parameter expansion and is not otherwise used for quoting).

   With `failglob` or `nullglob` options on, that would mean:

   ```
   $ PF='printf %s\n' bash-5.0 -O failglob -c '$PF test'
   bash-5.0: no match: %s\n
   $ PF='printf %s\n' bash-5.0 -O nullglob -c '$PF test%d'
   test0
   ```

   And even without those options:

   ```
   $ PF='printf %s\n' bash-5.0 -c '$PF test'
   test
   $ touch %sn
   $ PF='printf %s\n' bash-5.0 -c '$PF test'
   testn
   ```

See [@cas' fine answer](/a/679133) for what to do instead.